# Backpacking in Europe for the first time

Tags: budget, europe, camping, backpacking

I'm thinking of a solo backpacking trip in Europe starting June for 1 to 2 months. I should be flying in from Singapore to Paris and my budget would be about 1500 euros (excluding flight). I will also be roughing it out by camping with my tent in campsites (I have camping experience in tropical climates only but since i heard it's cheaper, i'll try it out). I will be using the trains to travel around while I'm there.

I was hoping to visit the following places (not in order)
Paris (duh...)
Amsterdam
Prague
Italy (unsure exactly where yet)
Switzerland (not sure too...)
... and maybe some other places in-between

I'm don't really care for the touristy areas but I'm interested in the historical and natural attractions aspects of Europe. I'm really into people watching and taking a slower approach rather than 'flashpacking'.

Is the budget too little?
perhaps some specific places to go(any suggestions?)
Any tips and hints for a female asian traveller?

Comment: and your question is? anyway, I met a guy from Netherlands who actually suggested me to try out couchSurfing.org... It's a great way to meet make new friends and cheaper accommodation.

Comment: Are you also interested in recommendations for places to visit?

Comment: I second @Phelios in trying out couchsurfing. Singapore has a decently active couchsurfing community that gets together for events and meet ups. You should try to meet with them before leaving to get some insight into the sort of people that do couchsurfing.

Answer (score 13):

I would not recommend a tent if you want to see the cities and rely on public transport:

- campsites are generally outside the city, near woods, lakes or the sea, since they are intended for recreation; unlike in the states or Australia where some people live there permanently
- and this also means there wont be much public transport near campsites

Leave your tent at home and stay in hostels. Most campsites do have cabins if you still want to go there without dragging your tent around, but at June/July the high season starts and peaks in August (summer holidays); so some campsites might be booked out.

1500 EUR does not look very realistic to me for 2 months. You will probably spent at least ~500 for trains if you want to see Paris, Amsterdam and Italy. Plan 30 EUR/day for accommodation and another 20 for food if you want to be on the safe side.

Comment: Hostels are less than 30 Euro a day, and if planning in advance, flights between those three cities with easyjet could save lots, as could rideshare or even buses (eurolines).  Agree with rest tho, +1 for pointing out camping is rare among backpackers.

Comment: @Mark Mayo♦: Where did you see hostels for less than 30 euro/day in French large cities? The average night will be above 45 euros in low-class hotels.

Comment: A cursory search on hostel pages on google get you prices from 25-35. But that's if you book in advance. So 30 € sounds reasonable

Comment: Well for example Le Montclair Montmartre in Paris is 19 Euros, and still gets an 80% rating (Hostelbookers).  Peace and Love Hostel is 20 Euros.  Young and Happ Hostel is 20 Euros.  Friends Hostel is 18 Euros. Blue Planet is 20 Euros.  These may not be the big chain hostels or the ones with package tours from the front door, but it does give you options.

Comment: You're living on the edge, Mark :) I would not expect to find a 20 EUR hostel in each town. Even if so, all the cheap rooms might be booked out; especially during high season.

Answer (score 10):

Whether the budget is sufficient depends on several things:

- Which countries you are going to, the ones you are mentioning are all
  on the expensive side
- How you travel, getting a rail pass helps but hitch-hiking or ride
  sharing is cheaper
- How much you spend on drinks and going out.
- Whether you eat in restaurants, fast food joints or cook in hostel
  kitchens.
- How many tours you do or sites with entrance fees you want to visit.
- Form of local transport: taxis, public or walking everywhere
- Accommodation, even camp sites are not always cheap. You can do couch
  surfing, hostels or cheap hotels.

So as you can see it is very hard to say whether a certain budget is enough without knowing the way you travel.

Over the years of travelling you learn many small things that help saving money but for the first time in another continent you will usually try to be on the safe side and spend a bit more rather than taking any risks.